Does amending the initial commit of a branch change the merge base?
All of this was performed in Xcode and not terminal. I branched main to create the development branch. On development, I made a few tweaks and instead of committing them, I amended them. Now, when I attempt to merge development into main, I'm met with the error "no merge base found (-3)".
If instead of amending the changes, I commit them, there is no error. Should I have committed the changes instead of amending them to prevent this error? And did I receive this error as a fault of my own or should Xcode have been able to perform this merge?

What does "appended the changes to the initial commit" mean? I want to know what both pieces mean: "appended the changes", and also "the initial commit". I have a feeling that "appended" means you did a "commit --amend" or interactive rebase, and that  "the initial commit" means the commit on main from before the branch itself had any separate commits.

@matt "amended", sorry.

And "the initial commit"?

@matt I'm doing this all through Xcode UI, not terminal, and so when I created the development branch, its repo history says that this new branch is the "initial commit". And so when I changed development, I amended the changes to this "initial commit", instead of committing them.

You mean it was the initial commit of the entire repository?

@matt that is correct

Were there any further commits on main after that?

@matt main was never modified

So there was only one commit at all?

@matt I can recreate this in Xcode very easily and I assume you can also. Again, only using the UI and not terminal. If I create a new branch from main, modify it, and commit it, I can merge it back into main without a problem. However, if instead of committing it, I amend it, I cannot merge it back into main because of the "no merge base found" error.

I've given my answer, based on the information you have revealed.

I cannot recommend doing any Git-related work directly in Xcode. Its Git integration is atrocious, and won't help you understand Git. Don't commit in Xcode, don't amend in Xcode, don't even switch branches in Xcode. Learn Git — actual Git — and work at the command line.

Say git log development to learn the SHA of the amended commit (i.e. after it was amended) and say
git switch main
git reset --hard <the-SHA>

This will point main at the same commit you amended. You will then be able to merge development into main (although there will be little point in doing so, because as far as I can tell from your question they are the same commit; either that or you'll get a fast-forward, if you did more stuff than you have revealed in your question).

This fixes the problem but did I encounter my error as a fault of my own or because of Xcode?

@phd oops, I'll fix

@lurningtookoad It is your responsibility to know what your tools does so it all falls back to you in the end :P

Wont this end up giving him problems if he ever tries to push main again? You are basically rewriting history of main here. (edit. nevermind... initial commit... got it...)
